# What to choose: Stored Procedure of Dynamic SQL in Postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, stored-procedures

This is a Postgres specific question. I am in a middle of the classic design situation where I have to decide whether to use Stored Procedure or Dynamic SQL (Prepared statement). I have read a lot and lot of blogs regarding the same and have come to conclusion that with current implementation of advanced database systems, there isn't any specific attribute that would weigh one over the other. 
Hence my question is being Postgresql specific.

```
What I want to ask is, are there advantages or disadvantages of using Stored Procedures in Postgres?
```

More about my design: As we are using Postgres specific functions like width_bucket and relying on various other things like Partitioning and Inheritance that Postgres provides, it is unlikely that we would switch to any other database provider in future. Our queries would be complex queries involving building of graphs and reports from the real time/ non-real time data.
There also would be some analytics built. Moreover, we would also be planning of sharding and partitioning our database. 
I want view points on the use of Stored Procedure with the type of system and environment I have describe above, specific to Postgresql. 
I would also like to understand how query optimization and execution works in Postgres.

Comment: Use both? There's pros and cons on both sides, neither are a silver bullet. I've never worked on an application that never needed stored procs, but select by id is totally overkill for a stored proc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so your question is whether to create sql on the client side and send it to the server, vs stored procedures.  Note, usually if you use stored procedures, you still have to create the sql that calls them so it is not purely an either/or.  So this is about a relational interface vs stored procedures.

Additionally it is worth noting that a key question is whether this is a database owned by an application or something that many applications may use.  In the former, you may not worry about encapsulation, but in the latter you want to think about your database as having a service interface.

So if it is "my application has a database and all material use goes through my application" then go with dynamic SQL against the underlying tables.

If your database has one or more applications, however, you want to make sure you can change your database structure without breaking any or all of your databases.  This usually means encapsulating access behind some sort of abstract interface.  This can be a use of VIEWs or stored procedures.

Views have an advantage that they can be directly manipulated in SQL, and are very flexible.  This allows wide-open retrieval (and with some work storage) of data behind them.  The application does not need to know how data is physically stored, just how to access it.

Stored procedures have the same benefit of encapsulation but provide a much more limited interface.  They also have the problem that usually people use them in ways that require a fixed number of arguments, so adding an argument requires close coordination of updates for the db and the application (Oracle's revision based editions are a solution to this problem but PostgreSQL has nothing similar).  However, one can discover arguments and handle them appropriately at run-time with a little work.

All in all this is a wide question and the specifics will be more important than generalities.

Comment: Can you give me pointers on how should I evaluate various things for Postgres?

Comment: By the time you get to PostgreSQL-specific concerns, you will be far enough along to recognize them.  My advice would be start with the general and then learn more about the db as you go.

Comment: Additionally, I would point out, the super-advanced functionality of PostgreSQL is easily abused if you don't get the db fundamentals right.  Most of the advanced functionality is great when you need it, but exotic solutions to exotic problems